# Scrolling problems with touchscreen and openjfx on linux using GTK

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, gtk3, gtk2

I am currently working on a touchscreen focused kiosk-type application with a list of videos. The user will scroll to the video he wants to see using the touchscreen, and press on it to view it. I am running this on an intel NUC with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed. This is the lsusb info of the touchscreen:

```
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 2575:0401 Weida Hi-Tech                CoolTouchR System
```

I am writing this application in java/javafx because it is what I'm most comforable with.

When I'm using GTK3 (default), the application does not respond to any touch screen events,
I found [here](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/329#issuecomment-459433106), that I can use `-Djdk.gtk.version=2` to force java to use GTK2. This works, for normal touch inputs, but when I start scrolling the screen snaps back, after the user moves his finger without touching the screen to scroll farther than the screen allows. This only happens on Linux in javaFX applications. GTK applications, like the Ubuntu applications store do not have to problem.

You can see it happening in this gif I recorded.
Watch the scrollbar/numbers when I start dragging from the bottom to go down.
[Gif link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBnIs.gif)

I have tried using different versions of java/javafx:

- Oracle JDK 8
- OpenJDK 8
- OpenJDK 11 + Gluon OpenJFX 11 (tried v15 aswell)
- Liberica OpenJRE 8 full

All of them gave the exact same problems with GTK2/GTK3

The code to replicate this error is as follows:

```java
public class App extends Application {
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        VBox vBox = new VBox();

        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            vBox.getChildren().add(new Label("Label: "+i));
        }
        ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane(vBox);
        scrollPane.setPannable(true);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(scrollPane));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to find a fix yet, has someone else encountered this before? Does anyone know how to fix this? Thanks

Comment: Use a `ListView`. You probably just have too many `Nodes` and are killing all of your memory.

Comment: Looking at the link you provided, there is a chance this is a bug that has not been fixed.

Comment: @Sedrick I'm just creating a lot of nodes to have content to scroll through, this isn't how I programmed it in the actual implementation. The bug behaves the exact same.